# How to make this slider stop at the final slide?

Tags: jquery, slideshow

I have a carousel text that automatically plays through without stopping. Is there a way to make it stop at the last word? Here is the code http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kyiqn

```
(function () {
    rt.Homepage = function () {
        function e() {
            var e = this;
            this.currentCaption = 0, this.$carousel = $(".js-carousel"), this.$captions = $(".js-captions"), this.switchCaption(1), setInterval(function () {
                return e.advanceCaption()
            }, 2000), this.addHandlers()
        }
        return e.prototype.addHandlers = function () {}, 

        e.prototype.advanceCaption = function () {
            var e, t;
            return this.currentCaption++, t = 20, e = this.currentCaption % t + 1, this.switchCaption(e)
        }, e.prototype.switchCaption = function (e) {
            var t, n, r, i, s, o, u = this;
            n = "state-1 state-2 state-3 state-4 state-5 state-6 state-7 state-8 state-9 state-10 state-11 state-12 state-13 state-14 state-15 state-16 state-17 state-18 state-19 state-20", this.$carousel.removeClass(n).addClass("state-" + e), o = this.$captions;
            for (i = 0, s = o.length; i < s; i++) t = o[i], r = $(".caption-" + e, t).width(), $(t).width(r);
            return _.delay(function () {
                return u.$carousel.addClass("show-caption")
            }, 500)
        }, e
    }(), $(function () {
        return new rt.Homepage
    })
}).call(this);
```

Comment: You should post up the code here, instead of just linking to it. Also, it looks like this the javascript's been compiled in some way, do you have the original?

Comment: Are you using a particular carousel library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've edited it to do what you want, and I've made the javascript (slightly) clearer so you can see what's going on. If you do have the un-minified javascript, I would recommend making similar edits to that instead.

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hFvyo)

```
(function () {
    rt.Homepage = function () {
        function e() {
            var e = this;
            this.currentCaption = 0;
            this.$carousel = $(".js-carousel");
            this.$captions = $(".js-captions");
            this.switchCaption(1);

            // set a variable for the interval, so we can stop it later
            this.interval = setInterval(function () {
                return e.advanceCaption()
            }, 1500);

            this.addHandlers();
        }

        e.prototype.addHandlers = function () {}

        e.prototype.advanceCaption = function () {
            this.currentCaption++;

            // if currentCaption reaches final caption, stop the interval
            if (this.currentCaption >= 4) {
                clearInterval(this.interval)
            }

            return this.switchCaption(this.currentCaption + 1);
        }

        e.prototype.switchCaption = function (e) {
            var t, n, r, i, s, o, u = this;
            n = "state-1 state-2 state-3 state-4 state-5";
            this.$carousel.removeClass(n).addClass("state-" + e);
            o = this.$captions;
            for (i = 0, s = o.length; i < s; i++) t = o[i];
            r = $(".caption-" + e, t).width(), $(t).width(r);
            return _.delay(function () {
                return u.$carousel.addClass("show-caption")
            }, 500)
        }

        return e;
    }(), $(function () {
        return new rt.Homepage
    })
}).call(this);
```